# GAS: HtmlService.getUserAgent() returns null when using V8

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, user-agent

If you use following GAS code with Rhino engine, the browser information will be shown on the log.

```
function baz() {
  var foo = HtmlService.getUserAgent();  
  Logger.log(foo);
  return 1;
}
```

But if you run it with V8 engine, it will show "null".
How can I fix it or is there any workaround?
Thank you.

Issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149247107

Comment: Create a issue in the issue tracker. You can find more about the issue tracker in the [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Thank you! I filed it.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149247107

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#getuseragent), it returns null for most script executions if not used in a web app's doGet() or doPost() function.

Nevertheless, i've executed your function and it returns the content... can you give us any clues?

**EDIT:**

Seems like it doesn't works yet with V8 runtime. I don't know if this will solve your problem but you can call it by vanilla JS and return it to the server using the [Navigator object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp).

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  // Retrieve and process any URL parameters, as necessary.
  if (e.parameter.folderId) {
    template.folderId = e.parameter.folderId;
  } else {
    template.folderId = 'root';
  }

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
    .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function baz(userAgent) {
  //var foo = HtmlService.getUserAgent();  
  Logger.log("userAgent: " + userAgent);

  return 1;
}
```

**JavaScript.html**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Run initializations on web app load.
   */
  $(function() {
    // Call the server here to retrieve any information needed to build the page.
    var ua = loadUserAgent();
    google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(function(contents) {
            // Respond to success conditions here.
          })
       .withFailureHandler(function(msg) {
            // Respond to failure conditions here.
          })
       .baz(ua);
  });

  function loadUserAgent() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;

    return ua;
  }

</script>
```

**appscript.json**

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "MYSELF",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Check it out!

Comment: Thank you.
Please be noted my situation.

(1) Firstly I called the HtmlService.getUserAgent() function from the doGet() function of my WebApp with Rhino runtime.

(2) When I opened the Script Editor today, it suggested me that you can change the runtime to V8

(3) So I turned it to V8 but the WebApp turned that it cannot detect  the browser information

(4) So I created the small script as above

(5) I found it *can* run with Rhino runtime but it *cannot* wun with V8.

I hope I could tell you my problem.
Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
Your idea is that invoke navigator.userAgent from the client-side JavaScript and it works!
Actually, I didn't need to run it from baz() function so I will add my shortened version.
Thanks again. You really saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Juan's Answer, I could resolve my problem.

The code in the answer could not work somehow and it was rather hard to fix it, but I got the concept that use client side JS instead of GAS service.

Actually, I didn't need to run the GAS function like baz() that I have written, but I just need to get the browser info in my environment.

My junior code is as below:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
   var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
   document.getElementById("browserInfo").innerText = userAgent;
</script>
<p id="browserInfo">BROWSERINFO</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  return template.evaluate()
    .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
}
```

I confirmed that if you publish it as the GAS WebApps, it works.

For my purpose, it's enough.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The issuetracker has been updated.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149247107

In summary:
 - Google updated the HtmlService.getUserAgent()
 - NOW It RETURNS CORRECT UserAgent info if you call it in the doGet() in the WebApps
 - STILL It RETURNS NULL if you call it in the Hello World like script in the Script Editor

I don't know it's the intentional spec change or unexpected error so I'm still questioning.

If (and only IF) you got the free time, please refer to my long comment including the video and enjoy! :D